# java needs to run twice before executing the command

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
  method();
  y();
  boolean x = true;
        if(x == y()){
           System.out.println("You're right!");

        }else{
            System.out.println("You're wrong!");
            main(args);
  }
}


    public static void method(){
        System.out.println("a+b=5 If a=2 what does b equal?"); 
}
    public static boolean y(){
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = s.nextLine();
            int input2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int b = 3;
            if(input2 == b)  {
                return true;

            }else{
             return false;
  }
}

            catch( Exception e ) {
                return false;
    }
  }
}
```

So , I'm running this in eclipse and i need to enter 3(right answer, You're right should be printed out) twice for it to work.
What I'm trying to do is pose a question and say you're wrong if wrong answer but keep letting input be written and say you're right if right answer and stop there.

```
a+b=5 If a=2 what does b equal? // first output
3 // my input + enter, nothing happens
3 // i enter the input again
You're right! // it only works the second time
```

Comment: Why did you call `y()` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your y() call at the top of the class. There is no need for it there.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
method();

boolean x = true;
    if(x == y()){
       System.out.println("You're right!");

    }else{
        System.out.println("You're wrong!");
        main(args);
  }
}


public static void method(){
    System.out.println("a+b=5 If a=2 what does b equal?"); 
}
public static boolean y(){
    try{
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        int input2 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int b = 3;
        return input2 == b;
}

        catch( Exception e ) {
            return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Also, in your y() the if clause is redundant. You can simply return input2==b. This will return true or false based on the calculations.

Comment: Thanks guys.I'm still new to programming. This helped a lot.